# Why does the built-in metric "vus" in .json output not reflect the console output?

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

In the console output of K6 you can easily see how many VUs are currently active.
See picture [image: k6 console output]

In the .json output there is a metric "vus" and a metric "vus_max".
I would expect "vus" to reflect the number of currently active virtual users.
However, in my .json output, except for the entries where "vus" is 0, "vus" and "vus_max" always have the same value. See picture [image: k6 .json output]

Is this a bug?
If not, how to generate the correct number of active VUs in the .json output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the k6 gitHub this is "something halfway between a bug and a missing feature".
This is the issue:
https://github.com/k6io/k6/issues/1977